# Linux - compare system date with date in file and send e-mail to admin

Tags: linux, bash, email, cron

I have a tacacs+ server running on Debian 7.8. I used the apt-get install tacacs+ to get the tacacs+ installed, so nothing special here. I use the tacacs+ to authenticate users in a Cisco VPN machine.

My problem is that I couldn't find anything developed already for tacacs+ to send e-mails to users/server admins  before their password expire. There is a possibility to ask an user to change the password on logon, but if the account is already expired, it doesn't work.

Below is a sample of the account setup for an user in tac_plus.conf file.

```
user = example.user {
default service = permit
login = des some_crypted_pass_here
expires = "Sep 30 2016"
}
```

Could you please provide a script that can compare the date in "expires" with the system date, and if less than 14 days are left till system date = expires, to send an automated e-mail to a specific address ( e.g. admin@domain.local ) with a warning message ( e.g. "The tacacs+/Cisco VPN account for example.user will expire in X days" ) ?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a site to ask people to do all the work for you.

Comment: Emil, I agree that I basically asked the whole script to do that. I wouldn't do that If I would have known where to start from. I'm sure someone already had some similar issue and maybe is willing to share some of his knowledge.

Comment: @MarinNedea One could use sed/grep/cut/awk (I would pick awk) to extract the date, then used `date -d` to convert it to seconds-since-epoch, then use bash to subtract it from the current date to determine if the two weeks had elapsed, then use `mail` to send the email.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John1024 After following your advice, I came up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#location of temporary file to store the results
temp_file=/usr/local/src/temp_file_tacacs 

#grep | cut | awk in the file /etc/tacacs+/tac_plus.conf and exporting resuts to temporary file
grep -e "user\|expires" /etc/tacacs+/tac_plus.conf | cut -d'=' -f 2 | tr -d { | tr -d \" | awk 'NR%2{printf $0":";next;}1' > $temp_file 

#Getting current system date 
date_current=$(date "+%s")  

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        #getting the user 
        user=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
        #getting the expiration date coresponding to the user
        date_expire=$(echo $line | awk -F: '{print $2}' | xargs) 
        #converting the date in the same format as $date_current ( was retrieved earlier )
        date_converted=$(date -d "$date_expire" +"%s")
        #calculating the difference between the 2 dates
        date_diff=$(expr $date_converted - $date_current)

        #checking if result is < 14 days ( 1209600 seconds = 14 days )
        if [ $(expr $date_diff - 1209600) -gt 0 ] 
        then
                #echo "$user - more than 14 days untill account will expire."  #left here for debugging purposes

                #ignoring there results and sending them to /dev/null ( just because I needed something in the while - then - else loop). 
                echo "" > /dev/null  
        else
                #echoing the results and sending them with with sendmail
                #If sendmail is not sending, check your /var/log/exim4/mailnlog.
                #I had to dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config and select "internet sites" option to be able to send e-mails to remote domains. Check
                # http://chepri.com/jake-strawn-fixed-mailing-to-remote-domains-not-supported-debian-5-lenny/ for more info about this 

                #NOTE: For each result, you will get a  different e-mail. If too many accounts are about to expire, you may be blocked by the mail server for spamming!!

                echo -e "Hello Admins,\\n\\nThe $user Cisco VPN Account will expire in less than 14 days!" | /usr/bin/mail -s "The Cisco VPN Account for $user is about to expire" "email@domain.com" 

        #END of the while loop  
        fi

done < "$temp_file"

#deleting the temporary file
rm -rf $temp_file
```